# calculating a probability using markov's inequality

Tags: statistics

How can I calculate $P(X>1)$ for $Mx(t)=1/(1-t)$ using  markov's inequality?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $X$ is a non-negative r.v. (which should be true as the mgf looks like the one for an $\text{Exp}(1)$ distribution). Note that Markov's inequality only gives a upper bound for the probability instead of an exact probability. We find the first moment of $X:$ \begin{align*}
M'_X(t)&=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{1-t}=\frac{1}{(1-t)^2}\\ \mathbb E(X)&=M'_X(0)=\frac{1}{(1-0)^2}=1
\end{align*}
By Markov's inequality, $${\displaystyle \mathbb P (X\geq a)\leq {\frac {\mathbb E(X)}{a}}\longrightarrow \mathbb P(X>1)=\mathbb P(X\ge 1)\le \frac{1}{1}=1}$$
(it might sound like a meaningless conclusion, but that's all Markov's inequality can tell you in this case.)